# CRUD PHP no ingresa datos

Tags: php, pdo, crud

Tengo estos valores dentro de un case:

```
case 'upgrade':
        $alm->__SET('acronimo', $_REQUEST['acro']);
        $alm->__SET('cantidad', $_REQUEST['cantidad']); 
        $alm->__SET('compania', $_REQUEST['comp']);

        $model->Actualizar1($alm);

        break;

    case 'registrar':
        $alm->__SET('acronimo', $_REQUEST['acro']);
        $alm->__SET('cantidad', $_REQUEST['cantidad']); 
        $alm->__SET('compania', $_REQUEST['comp']);

        $model->Registrar($alm);
        break;
```

Y este es el formulario:

```
<table>
       <tr>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
              <td colspan="2">
              <select class="form-control" id="acro" name="acro" required>
                     <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?> </option>    
                     <?php
                     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=final', 'root', '');
                     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                     $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from articulos order by acronimo');
                     $stmt->execute();
                     while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                     echo '<option name="' . ($row['acronimo']) . '">' . ( $row['acronimo'] . '(' . $row['descripcion'] .')' ) . '</option>';
                     }
                     ?>
             </select>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left;">Cantidad</th>
               <td colspan="2">
                   <input class="form-control version" type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('cantidad') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required />
               </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Compañia</th>
              <td colspan="2">
              <select class="form-control" id="comp" name="comp" required>
              <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?> </option>    
              <?php
              $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=final', 'root', '');
               $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
               $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select * from compania order by acronimo');
               $stmt->execute();
               while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               echo '<option name="' . ($row['acronimo']) . '">' . ( $row['acronimo'] . '(' . $row['nombre'] .')' ) . '</option>';
               }
               ?>
               </select>
               </td>
               <td><input type="hidden" name="acronimo" id="acronimo" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
               <td><input type="hidden" name="compania" id="compania" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('compania') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="boton" value="Guardar" /></td>
              <td colspan="2"> 
                 <a href="index.php">
                 <input type="reset" class="button_active" value="Reset" />
                 </a>
                 </td>
                 <td colspan="2"> 
                 <a href="index.php">
                 <input type="button" onclick="limpiarFormulario()" value="Limpiar Edición">
                  </a>
              </td>
          </tr>
 </table>
```

Y no se ver exactamente donde falla, se que en las sentencias de INSERT del otro archivo no, por que las e usado con otro form y funcionan perfectamente, falla aquí en el form pero no se donde

Las public function:

```
public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO stock (acronimo,cantidad,compania)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
                            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
                            $data->__GET('cantidad'),
                            $data->__GET('compania')
                        )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
public function Actualizar1(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO stock (acronimo,cantidad,compania)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
                            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
                            $data->__GET('cantidad'),
                            $data->__GET('compania')
                        )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo por ningún lado las sentencias `INSERT ...` de las que hablas.

Comment: que es lo que te falla, la insersión o la actualización, tendrías que mostrar también la función Actualizar1 y la función Registrar

Comment: ahora estan fallando ambos los ingreso enseguida

Comment: ya están las funciones al final del post, gracias. por si os parece extraño que las dos sean insert, es por que mi jefe quería que Actualizar 1 recogiera los valores de un registro ya insertado y con Actualizar1 solo cambiando la clave principal se ingresara, en las demás tablas funciona pero en esta no. El fallo proviene del dato de compañía porque si realizo Actualizar1 sin cambiar compañía funciona un vez lo modifico no hace nada

Comment: Sería bueno que revises el `error_log`, a simple vista podría ser un problema de violación de constraint de unicidad, quizá estés intentando registrar datos que ya existen o que violan los posibles índices únicos que tengas en la tabla `stock`.